# Transparent Backgroug with InfoPath 2013 Forms

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I hope someone might be able to help me with this. I am using SharePoint 2013 to create forms that users can fill in as a request for example. However I am then designing the form with InfoPath 2013. When published back to sharepoint it creates a white background and the site background has a transparency, this is a problem.

So I'm looking to have no background for the form so it looks more reasonable when accessing it on the website. If anyone could help me with this I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: There is a community dedicated to [SharePoint](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/). This question does not belong here

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to set the view background(s) as a tiled transparent image.